# PHP redirect all page call through FrontContoller

Tags: php

I'm developing a customer FrontController in my PHP application. I need to route all URL invocation through the FrontController.

Say if someone type the bellow URL on a browser,

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/pages/admin/stock-maintenance.php
```

I need it to be route through my FontController.php and fetch all necessary data to that specific page

I'm having my FrontController.php in following directory and currently it was written to capture other requests such as form submits and hyper-link clicks in a following manner

```
http://www.mydomain.com/control/FrontController.php
```

---

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['stock-quick_search'])) {
    $view       = PAGES.'user/stock-search-list.php';
} 
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['stock-manage_stocks'])) {
    $view       = PAGES.'admin/stock-maintenance.php';
}
```

How can I capture and route direct page URL invocations through my controller using .htaccess file?

Note: I'm new to PHP and I have very little knowledge on .htaccess file coding

Thanks in advance

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: @ RageZ I'm not using any framework

Comment: would be difficult for us to help you on your own framework ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using a `.htaccess` file to define URL rewriting via Apache server. The other way is to get the `REQUEST_URI` and `explode` it to an array, next you can get each part to check. But the first solution that I spoke is more better that this one.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to learn how this is being done is to check other frameworks around (e.g. Zend Framework). They use `mod_rewrite` to forward all requests to a specific PHP file. Check http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html (search for `RewriteEngine`).

I assume if you are not familiar with `.htaccess`, you won't be familiar with Apache HTTP server as well. So I recommend you to check the official documentation. Once you get basic thought how the server works, it is quite easy to work with its configuration (including `.htaccess`).

Btw. `mod_rewrite` documentation is here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Always check the version you are reading! MahanGM in other answer linked to obsolete documentation (version 1.3)!

Comment: Try to use the official `mod_rewrite` documentation and _decipher_ the Zend Framework example. It will give you nice insight in what is being done there. If you will have problems with that, just write back here :).